# obj.count = 8 or setattr(obj, 'count', 8)

Tags: python, oop, methods, var

In python. What is the difference between using the `setattr(object, 'var', value` and the `object.var = value` method. They both seem to do the same thing

```
class Something(object):
    pass

x = Something()

setattr(x, 'count', 2) #sets count to be 2
x.count = 3            #sets count to be 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They indeed do the same thing, but you cannot use a variable with the attribute setting syntax, while you *can* do that with `setattr()`.

In other words, this works:

```
foo = 'count'
setattr(x, foo, 2)
```

but this doesn't:

```
foo = 'count'
x.foo = 2
```

Use `setattr()` for *dynamic* attribute setting, where the name of the attribute is taken from a variable. Use `object.attributename = value` for *static* attributes, where you know the name beforehand.

In addition, the attribute access syntax is limited to proper Python identifiers, while `setattr()` can use *any* string. This means that you can use:

```
setattr(x, '3 little piggies', 42)
```

where attempting that with static attributes will not work because Python identifiers do not allow for spaces, and cannot start with digits.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, they are essentially the same. However, `setattr(obj, 'attr', value)` is more general, in that it allows you to do things that you can't do via the syntactic construct `obj.attr = value`:

```
>>> class A(object):
...    pass
>>> a = A()
>>> setattr(a, 'foo bar', 5)  # space in the attribute name???
>>> print getattr(a, 'foo bar')
5
>>> a.'foo bar' = 7
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a.'foo bar' = 7
          ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Whether you *should* take advantage of this "feature" of Python (hint: you probably shouldn't) is another question.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing `x.count` directly yields more efficient code, I suspect that's because the property access can be resolved at parse/byte-compiling time. This would probably be especially noticeable in a loop.

Given

```
def f(): setattr(x, 'count', 2)
def g(): x.count = 3
```

Here's what [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) says on Python 2.7:

```
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (setattr)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('count')
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            3
             15 POP_TOP
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(g)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x)
              6 STORE_ATTR               1 (count)
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

So `g` yields less bytecode, and I suspect it's faster as well.